# C# custom action after InstallInitialize using WiX

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I have created a simple C# custom action.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult MySimpleAction(Session session)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It works!");
    return ActionResult.Success;
}

<Binary Id="myAction" 
        SourceFile="MyApp.CA.dll"/>

<CustomAction Id="myActionId" 
              BinaryKey="myAction" 
              DllEntry="MySimpleAction" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="myActionId" 
              After="InstallInitialize">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I got error 2762, when I ran the installation.

When I run

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="myActionId" 
            Before="InstallFinalize">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I didn't get the error. Why can't I run after InstallInitialize? How is it run?

Comment: When running during InstallInitialize, does executing as immediate instead of deferred make any difference?

Comment: I need do my custom action before install files

Comment: When I changed Execute to immediate I not seen error but installation was not sucessful

Comment: I guess you need to install with the verbose log enabled to provide you with more diagnostics. `msiexec /i MyApplication.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write:

```
<CustomAction Id="myActionId" BinaryKey="myAction" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
```

With `Execute="deferred"` it will not work.

Besides this, in CusomAction.config it must be written:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both after [InstallIntialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and before [InstallFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should work. Take a look at your built MSI using [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and take a look at the [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Sort it by column *Sequence*. Does it look to be scheduled correctly? A logfile will also be helpful.